# not able to display console data in web page

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, jsx

i am beginner in react . when i fetch request from API, i got data in console ,but when i am trying to display data in web page in that time data isn't show.
I want to display data in web page.

here is my console log
https://ibb.co/YLmLQz1

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Movie from './components/Movies';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <div className='container'>
        <Movie />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

> Header.js

In header file i created my navbar and search form

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Header = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

  return (
    <div className="jumbotron">
      <h1 className="display-1">
        <i className="material-icons brand-icon">LatestMovie</i> Movie
        </h1>
      <div className="input-group w-50 mx-auto">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Search Your Movie..."
          value={search}
          onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <button className="btn btn-dark">
            Search Movie
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

> Movies.js

here i fetch my movies request throght axios

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios';

const Movie = () => {

    const [movies, setMovie] = useState([]);

    const apiurl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=642b793e&s=marvel"

    const getMovies = async () => {
        const res = await Axios.get(apiurl);
        console.log(res);

        setMovie(res.data.hits);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getMovies();
    }, []);


    return (
        <div className='row'>
            {
                movies && movies.map(movie => (
                    <div className='col-md-3'>
                        <div className='card'>
                            <div className='card-body'>
                                <h4>{movie.Year}</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Movie;
```

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(res);`?

Comment: wait i will share

Comment: your movies are in `res.data.Search` not in `res.data.hits`

Comment: Thanku sir for help